# iOS Send File to Review Application-Loader (Apple Watch)

Tags: application-loader, ios8-extension, watchkit, apple-watch

Can I send the apple watch apps For Review RightNow if Yes which file for review will be sent (Application-Loader) because we have a many file in Products Folder

Comment: No you cannot submit your watch apps yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot and the reason is: right now to write Watch app you are using Xcode Beta version and it is not possible to submit app to AppStore from Beta version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Watch apps and their associated WatchKit extensions are not submitted separately. They are bundled inside an iPhone app for both submission and distribution.

It is not currently possible to submit an app with a Watch app and WatchKit extension... it will be rejected as using private APIs.

However, it is a requirement that the containing iPhone app provides useful functionality in its own right. Therefore, you may wish to submit a build of that iPhone app for review in the meantime, without the embedded WatchKit app. To do this, it is not sufficient to exclude the WatchKit extension and Watch app from your target. You would need to create a branch of your code that actually excludes the WatchKit content, as the submitted app must be built with the shipping version of Xcode (6.1) which does not recognise WatchKit code.